# When does GLSurfaceView begin to work?

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I have a class `GLView extends GLSurfaceView`.
 It can run when i defined it in `layout.xml` or used it as the `contentView`. `onSurfaceCreated()`,`onSurfaceChanged()`and `onDrawFrame()` were all called.
But if i only wirte `GLView view = new GLView(context);view.setRenderer(renderer);`, is it possible to run? 
And i don't want it to be the `contentView`, i just need it to run `onDrawFrame()`again and again.

Comment: You want the renderer thread to run, but you don't want the output to appear?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, you could define your layout so that the GLSurfaceView's View is behind everything else. Then the output will be covered by the other views. Not sure what you're hoping to accomplish with this.

Comment: I want to use opengl es to do gpgpu, but i found that opengl es and glSurfaceView are bound together. So i can't use opengl api without glSurfaceview. i already have video screen output, just want to do something with opengl es in background. And i'm not sure if let the  GLSurfaceView View behind everything will effect the performance or not.

Comment: You don't need GLSurfaceView. See Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) for various examples, including TextureUploadActivity.java which does all its work on an offscreen pbuffer.